# I see an additional SSHD connection established from an IP that I don't recognise. Should I be worried? (output included)

Tags: linux, ssh, hacking

Here's the output (I've changed my IP to 23.23.23.23)

```
    [root@web01 centos]#  lsof -i tcp:22  
    COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME  
    sshd     3705   root    3u  IPv4   43164      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)  
    sshd     3705   root    4u  IPv6   43166      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)  
    sshd    32064   root    3u  IPv4 8676370      0t0  TCP web01.internal:ssh->49.235.10.177:33976 (ESTABLISHED)  
    sshd    32160   root    3u  IPv4 8673203      0t0  TCP web01.internal:ssh->23-23-23-23.static.isp.com:filesphere (ESTABLISHED)  
    sshd    32168 centos    3u  IPv4 8673203      0t0  TCP web01.internal:ssh->23-23-23-23.static.isp.com:filesphere (ESTABLISHED)
```

**The unknown IP: 49.235.10.177** - on a quick Google search I found out it's from China and has been reported for abuse a few times.

How bad is this? What should I do from here?

Answer (score 0):

You probably get a lot of those any day. Some bots try common user names/passwords on every internet facing sshd they can find.

You can do a `last` to see if there is an actual login (not just a connection) from an unknown address and check /var/log/auth. Note though that if the system was compromised you'll probably find nothing there.

And consider using `fail2ban` to automatically ban ip addresses that try to connect too many times.